# What changed in tomcat 7.0.42 -> 7.0.47 at EL-Escaping?

Tags: java, tomcat, el

What has changed in tomcat 7.0.42 -> 7.0.47 at EL-Escaping?

I have an include tag:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/elements/dataview.jspx">
    <jsp:param name="customParameter" value="{id:${object.id},action:\'${action}\'}" />
</jsp:include>
```

dataview.jspx contains

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var customParameter = '${param.customParameter}';
</script>
```

In tomcat 7.0.42 it renders to this:

```
var customParameter = '{id:4,action:\'add\'}';
```

But in 47 it renders this:

```
var customParameter = '{id:4,action:\&#039;add\&#039;}';
```

what changed? and how can i now output my js-variable?

Comment: I don't have access to the source, but I will try to look at it and confirm. I would guess that this is due to improper escaping. When rending into `<script>` tags, you should only have to escape the string for JavaScript. But it looks like the code is first escaping the string for JavaScript, and then *also* escaping it for HTML.

Comment: Actually, looking at this further, it appears that instead of escaping into JavaScript, it is escaping the string into HTML; it's not doing both.

Comment: Changelogs are your friend: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html   See note on 55642: Correct logic error in the JSP parser that was incorrectly identifying EL expressions in jsp:param element values as a literal string. (markt)

Comment: thanks i already took a look at them, but didn't find this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a workaround. I changed my "action" parameter to integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tomcat 7.0.47 does correctly. It is a bug of Tomcat 7.0.42.
Solution for your case is use JSTL function to wrap action value by single quote.

1. JSTL function

   public class Functions {

   ```
   public static String quote(String str) {
       if (str == null) {
           return null;
       }
       return ('\'' + str + '\'');
   }
   ```

   }
2. Create TLD for the function with uri: 'http://www.myapp.com/functions' and prefix is tf
3. Using your function

   action:${tf:quote(action)}

   **var customParameter = ${tf:quote(param.customParameter)};** // Eclipse will warn this but it is valid use.

   this will generate JS code like this

   **var customParameter = 'your_action_value';**

Comment: How is it doing it correctly? When escaping into JavaScript you don't want to escape into HTML. For example `<` within a `script` tag isn't converted into an HTML entity, and it shouldn't be.

Comment: Test it and see the result.

Comment: No, I'm asking you how it is *not* bug. How does it make sense to escape a quote to `&#039;` within JavaScript?

Comment: Did you use c:out with escapeXml = false.?

Comment: OP is not using `<c:out>`

Comment: Absolutely not. It doesn't *always* escape XML. The problem is not with the value that is resolved, but the resolved value being subsequently escaped by `jsp:param`.